# 'btnSubmit_Click' não é um membro de 'ASP.cliente_aspx'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, datepicker

Estou a criar um site em asp.net com uma master page. Quando tento colocar um datepicker dá-me erro.

Estou a recorrer a este [Site](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-UI-DatePicker-Calendar-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Estando o mesmo a dar o seguinte erro

> 'btnSubmit_Click' não é um membro de 'ASP.cliente_aspx'

Alguém me consegue ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO

Basta trocar o código `<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />` por `<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="btnSubmit_Click" />`, ou seja em vez de ser o evento **OnClick** é o evento **OnClientClick**

Comment: José, seria interessante explicar a diferença dos eventos `OnClick` e `OsClientClick` para deixar a resposta mais ilustrativa, porque na sua pergunta não mostra o código então deixa dúvida do que exatamente estava a fazer.